# Given two unital rings, R and S, how do we prove that φ(1R) = 1S?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was studying for an exam and chanced upon this question in my textbook. I was a bit confused as to how we would go about trying to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

*Suppose that R and S are unital rings (but not necessarily integral domains), that φ : R → S is a homomorphism, and that φ is onto.*

*Prove that φ(1R) = 1S.*

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$ is onto, any $y\in S$ is of the form $\phi(x)$ for some $x\in R$.  Then $\phi(1_R) y = \phi(1_R)\phi(x) = \phi(1_R x) = \phi(x) = y$.

This proves that $\phi(1_R)$ is a unit in $S$.  Units are unique by a standard argument.